# EF 6 + EF.Reverse.POCO.Generator mdf not initializing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In [this code](https://github.com/drydenmaker/EF.Reverse.Poco.Generator.Migrations) I used two approaches to generating POCOS, each in their own projects. One with the EF 6 designer, the other with Entity Framework Reverse Poco Code First Generator.  I then create an initializer extending `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` with nearly identical `Seed()` methods (naming conventions are different).  Then I created a test project for each, with one test method like:

```
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new PocoLagaInitializer());

        using (var context = new LagaModelDbContext())
        {
            var threadList = context.LoggerThreads.ToList();
            Assert.AreEqual(threadList.Count, 1);
        }

    }
```

The connection strings are exactly the same in all projects.:

```
<add name="LagaModel"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\LagaDatabase.mdf;Initial Catalog=Logging;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

The EF6 designer code creates the file, the POCO Generator errors:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot attach the file
>   'D:\\bin\Debug\LagaDatabase.mdf' as database 'Logging'.

Does anyone know what the difference is that causes this?

Comment: I did see that `\aPocoModel\Generated\LagaModelDbContext.cs` at line 37 sets a null database initializer.  This may be due to there not being a migration set for MigrationConfigurationFileName in `aPocoModel\Generated\LogaDatabase.tt` on line 34?

Comment: Can you include the MDF file so I can test it please.

Comment: The POCOs were actually generated from SQL server.  I added those scripts to Github.

Comment: Also, I found that when I set the **MigrationConfigurationFileName** value, this simple example seems to work.  I have another more complex project that I made that change to that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this code, see if it works for you
[www.hicrest.net/EF.Reverse.Poco.Generator.Migrations-SimonHughes.zip](http://www.hicrest.net/EF.Reverse.Poco.Generator.Migrations-SimonHughes.zip)

Comment: Thanks! I set the MigrationConfigurationFileName and I am off to the races!